# Solving ODE with jacobi amplitude

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

I am trying to find $v_0$ such that $$(x'(t))^2=v_0^2+\cos(x)-\dfrac 1{\sqrt 2}$$
$v_0>0$, $x(0)= \dfrac \pi 4$ and we want the solution to be bounded. In addition $x'(t)\neq 0$  $\forall t \in R$

---

and I am really stuck with trying to solve $$\int \dfrac { dx}{\sqrt{v_0^2+\cos(x)-1/\sqrt2}}=\pm t+c$$
How do I proceed?

Comment: What's the property of $v_0$ that you actually want? As in, the integral that you have here is well defined as long as $v_0^2>1+1/\sqrt{2}$. So what are the selection criteria for $v_0$?

Comment: In any case $\int (a+\cos(x))^{-1/2} dx$ in general is an elliptic integral of the first kind, unless $a$ is $\pm 1$.

Comment: @Ian yes I want $v_0>0$ and $x'(t)$ not equal to 0. plus the solution should be bounded.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not uniquely determined...have you done some numerics that suggest that this doesn't typically happen?

Comment: @ian I think that typically there are points t in R such that the $x'=0$

Comment: Oh, you want $x'$ never zero, not just not identically zero? If so don't you need to specify the initial condition for $x$ as well?

Comment: @ian $x(0)=pi/4$

Comment: So you want the solution connecting two saddle points (or the same saddle point on the torus) of the pendulum equation $x''=-\frac12\sin(x)$. The curve for that is $x'^2-\cos(x)=0^2-(-1)=1$.

Comment: @SpaceNugget You want to be helped, so you should provide all information like `x(0)=pi/4 `, etc. Click to edit button, and add (if any)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simulating the pendulum $x''=-\frac12\sin(x)$. The periodic solutions have points where the direction changes, that is, zero-crossings of the velocity. The rotational solutions are not bounded, the angle steadily increases. Thus the only solution that has the demanded characteristics connects the saddle points at $x=\pm\pi$. The integration constant of that solution is the same as at the saddle point, even if the solution never reaches it. This gives $$(x')^2=\cos(x)+1=2\cos^2(x/2)$$ along the solution and then $$v_0^2=1+\frac1{\sqrt2}$$ for the velocity at the angle $x=\frac\pi4$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int \dfrac {dx}{\sqrt {a + \cos(x) }} = \dfrac {2 \sqrt {a + \cos(x)}}{a + 1}$$

(F(x/2|2/(a + 1)))/sqrt(a + cos(x))) + constant. There is no way to avoid the F function I am afraid. Unless $v_0$ has some special property!

Comment: what is the F function? Where do I use it in the solution?